# Drag and drop for switching divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, drag, element

I'm looking for a drag and drop system for managing a tournament... I would like to know if someone would be able to show me one.

During my searches, I found a lot of this kind of system: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?http://konsolestudio.com/dad/ (placing elements between two others), but only one which I'm looking for: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?FJJGWHwC .

However, I tried to install this one and it's totally buggy, and nothing to get started... (unless I'm just bad for searching stuff?)

Well, sorry for my bad English, and I hope I explained correctly... Thank you for your help.

Comment: It might help to show us the code you've tried and what specifically goes wrong. Otherwise, maybe just keep looking around for a better plugin. I have often found [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) to be helpful [(droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager)).

Comment: My advice for picking out a good plugin: 1) Pick one that is more than a month old - 3-6 months should be your low end (only if it's very active), though exceptions could be made; 2) Pick a plugin with good documentation - make sure it has method calls, properties, options, etc. all documented and that it does what you need; 3) Pick a plugin that is extensible to the point you need and a little more, so you can enhance it now and in the future when new requirements arrive - make sure it has everything you want and a little more. This was not a good plugin choice. My recommendation: try again.

Comment: My code is simply stuff like that:

<?php echo $this->Html->script('dragndrop/assets/js/vendor/requirejs/require'); ?> 

under cakephp. And I got error messages everywhere around about those scripts.

Thanks for the tips, but at the point where I am, I'm able to take nearly anything, as long as it's usable...